# How to embed HTML into Java custom Dialog Box?

Tags: java, html, dialog

Can anyone explain to me (point me to right documentation) on how to embed an HTML page into Java dialog box? Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial on [How to use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) will show you how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the following code should work for you:

```
String htmlMsg = "<html>You can use</b>HTML here</html>";

JOptionPane dialogBox = new JOptionPane();
dialogBox.setMessage(msg);
dialogBox.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
//....
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the LGPL Flying Saucer libraries, it all depends on what you want to achieve with the HTML. It's got XHTML + CSS covered, but is less backwards compatible than other renderers.